# spring-cloud-kubernetes stops listening to ConfigMap events

Tags: azure, spring-boot, kubernetes, azure-aks, spring-cloud-kubernetes

My simple spring-boot 2.1.5.RELEASE running on Azure Kubernetes Service, responsible for listening to ConfigMap changes - receives 'Force closing'.

- spring-boot-starter-parent = 2.1.5.RELEASE
- spring-cloud-dependencies = Greenwich.SR1

Relevant configuration snippet:

```
cloud:
    kubernetes:
        reload:
            enabled: true
        secrets:
            enabled: false
```

after some time, AKS signals `Exec Failure java.io.EOFException: null` and the kubernetes-client tries to reconnect.

Eventually it succeeds with `WebSocket successfully opened` information, but within same second it also signals `Force closing the watch io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.WatchConnectionManager@59ec7020` and looks like it terminates the connect. No further updates on ConfigMap triggers any event :(

Permissions in general are set, as events are properly caught by the service for initial test runs:

```
- apiGroups: [""]
resources: ["services", "pods", "configmaps", "endpoints"]
verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

Does anyone come across similar problem, and could help me to narrow down potential root cause?

Comment: did you get anything on this ?

Comment: unfortunately not @Sikorski; we made a workaround that service responsible for listening on the changes and propagating information accordingly to "affected" services is restarted together with confing-map deployment